# What is "Television" in System Information report for an external monitor (that is not actually a TV)?

Tags: macos, mac, display, system-information

The [*System Information* report](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203001) for *Graphics/Displays* on my MacBook Pro Retina (Late 2013) shows the following info for the internal screen and for an external Acer monitor.

```
NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M:

  Chipset Model:    NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  PCIe
  PCIe Lane Width:  x8
  VRAM (Total): 2048 MB
  Vendor:   NVIDIA (0x10de)
  Device ID:    0x0fe9
  Revision ID:  0x00a2
  ROM Revision: 3776
  gMux Version: 4.0.8 [3.2.8]
  Displays:
Color LCD:
  Display Type: Retina LCD
  Resolution:   2880 x 1800 Retina
  Retina:   Yes
  Pixel Depth:  32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Built-In: Yes
Acer H236HL:
  Resolution:   1920 x 1080 @ 60Hz (1080p)
  Pixel Depth:  32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Display Serial Number:    LX1AA0034210
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Television:   Yes
```

What is the meaning of that last item, `Television: Yes`? This hardware is *not* actually a TV, just a display with HDMI, DVI, and VGA inputs.

I understand that modern TVs are indeed just monitors with an [OTA tuner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-air_programming) and speakers implanted. But I wonder, given the lack of a tuner, what the meaning of that item in the report specifically means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.What does Television:Yes mean?
It means your macbook is sending the color to your display not in RGB but in YCbCr space instead of RGB,which could lead to poor picture quality.

2.Solution:

Override an EDID [(Extended_Display_Identification_Data)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) setting to force the RGB colour space

[Threads](http://embdev.net/topic/284710#3027030)  about forcing RGB mode instead of YCbCr

You can force RGB mode by following [Turtorial on how to force RGB mode](http://www.mathewinkson.com/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor)

This is long standing bug that Apple refuses to fix and that is not simple to work around.

Comment: Can you cite some authoritative source about part 1 of your Answer? I'd feel better than about accepting this Answer to close the Question. And thanks for the info.

Comment: I tried before.When it's showing "Television:yes",my monitor's current colour space was always YCbCr just like others facing the same problem.Since I'm not a specialist in color space,i could not find proper authoritative document on this.Most answer to this question were based on tests.